# How do I achieve this in subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have table A :

```
genre   collection
horror   20
action   50
rom-com  30
sci-fi   90
```

and table B:

```
MovieId   genre     performance
1         sci-fi     Hit
2         rom-com    Hit
3         sci-fi     Flop
4         rom-com    Hit
5         rom-com    Hit
6         horror     Flop
7         horror     Flop
8         sci-fi     Hit
9         rom-com    Hit
```

I am trying to get a count of hits per genre and also sum of box office collection of movies which were a Hit .

So I trying to get something like:

```
genre     hit_movies     total_collection
horror     0              0
action     0              0
rom-com    4              120
sci-fi     2              180
```

I am trying this by using a subquery:

```
select genre, sum(total_collection) as total_collection  
    ,(select count(*) from  A  where genre = A.genre and A.performance = 'Hit') as hit_movies
    from 
    (select A.genre as genre ,
        (select sum(B.collection) from B  where B.genre = A.genre and A.performance = 'Hit')
        as total_collection from A  
    )x

group by 1
```

But I am not getting desired results. I am using postgresql. Any help is really appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tableA.genre, 
       COUNT(tableB.genre) hit_movies, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN tableB.genre IS NULL
                THEN 0
                ELSE tableA.collection
                END) total_collection
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.genre = tableB.genre AND tableB.performance = 'Hit'
GROUP BY tableA.genre
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8e76eddab961b9180c54fc613fd41ccb)

Option proposed by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) (PostgreSQL-specific):

```
SELECT tableA.genre, 
       COUNT(tableB.genre) hit_movies, 
       SUM(tableA.collection) FILTER (WHERE tableB.genre IS NOT NULL)  total_collection
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.genre = tableB.genre AND tableB.performance = 'Hit'
GROUP BY tableA.genre
```

The difference - first query outputs zeroes for the genres without hits whereas second one outputs NULLs. May be changed by replacing zero with NULL (or by replace the whole CASE expression with `CASE WHEN tableB.genre IS NOT NULL THEN tableA.collection END`) in the first query or by wrapping the expression with COALESCE() in the second query.